# Question closed as too broad because of the wrong belief?

Tags: support, closed-questions

I asked [this question](https://superuser.com/q/936088/282033) and was closed as too broad because of the statement that it would require upward hardware compatibility but **which is wrong**. *(ᴡɪɴ9x still works natively on latest hardware with limit cpuid maximum enabled and ≤1Gb RAM) (linux 2.2.0 for PowerPC still works on qemu)*

The problem lies with the bootloader *(including with the installation medium)* and this represent a narrowed scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has been reopened to give it one more time around the loop.

Bear in mind though that it is currently at -4 votes and has already been through reopen queue and failed to be reopened there.  As such this is a strong indication that the community in general believes that it is very low quality.

In order to improve your question, and thus prevent it simply being re-closed, I would advise you to provide evidence of

- what you have tried,
- what research you have done to conclude that this is indeed possible,
- *clear* detail of why you need or want this
- why your solution of using QEMU either does not work or is not suitable (you *have* tried it haven't you?)